# Why is the source only called once?

Tags: javascript, html

**Source**

```
function sayHello() {
   var time = timemore();
   time();
   time();
}

function timemore(){
    var cnt = 0; 
    document.write('<br />cnt : '+cnt);
    return function(){
        if(cnt<3){
            document.write('<br />start');
            cnt++;
        }else{
            document.write('<br />end'); 
        }
    }
}
sayHello();
```

**result**

```
cnt : 0
start
start
```

result is called twice
Why is 'document.write('
cnt : '+cnt);'... called only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is `document.write('cnt : '+cnt);`... called only once?

Because `document.write('<br />cnt : '+cnt);` is a line inside the method `timemore`, and you only call `timemore` once.

Let's break that down a little.

On line 2, you call `timemore`. This runs the `timemore` function (writing out the line in question), and returns another function, which you assign to the variable `time`. The function you return looks like this:

```
function(){
    if(cnt<3){
        document.write('<br />start');
        cnt++;
    }else{
        document.write('<br />end'); 
    }
}
```

So, now `time` is pointing to this function. As you can see, this function does not at any point call `document.write('<br />cnt : '+cnt);`. Therefore, no matter how many times you call the function `time`, that line isn't called any more.

Answer (score 0):

Because `document.write('<br />cnt : '+cnt);` is in the `timemore()`

The `var time = timemore()` means `time` will be the return value of `timemore()`

That is, after executing `timemore()`, variable `time` will be the following function

```js
function(){
        if(cnt<3){
            document.write('<br />start');
            cnt++;
        }else{
            document.write('<br />end'); 
        }
}
```

so the `timemore()` is actually executed just once.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a curry function. The inner function will be called each time time() is called. If you have another function inside the inner function, you may call it like time()().

[Reference/Read more about currying](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-currying-in-javascript)